# the action script is not getting triggered in form html when clicked on submit

Tags: html

I have form which has 1 checkbox to select my 11 checkboxes, the select option is working fine (i.e selecting all & viceversa), whereas when I click on submit, the action script is not getting called, please help.

```
<form id ="frm1">
<form action="/cgi-bin/voice/test/number_select/cluster1/php_checkbox.php" method="post">
<input type='checkbox'  name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll(frm1);' Value="Select all">Select All
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"     value="number1"><label>1.number1</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number2"><label>2.number2</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number3"><label>3.number3</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number4"><label>4.number4</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number5"><label>5.number5</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number6"><label>6.number6</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number7"><label>7.number7</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number8"><label>8.number8</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number9"><label>9.number9</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number10"><label>10.number10</label></div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="number11"><label>11.number11</label></div>

<div class=""><input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Two `<form>` tags?

Comment: I tried to keep one, but still the script was not triggered. can you amend the script ?

Comment: got the answer, we can close this.